How to display the monthly cost of WhatsApp Cloud API in my app's dashboard using conversation analytics api?
I'm building a WhatsApp module in my company's CRM app. I've successfully developed the module, but I'm facing an issue while trying to display the monthly charges of the WhatsApp Cloud API in the dashboard using the Conversation Analytics API.
Here is the API call I'm making to fetch the conversation analytics data:
https://graph.facebook.com/{{api-version}}/{{waba-id}}?fields=conversation_analytics.start(1656661480).end(1674859480).granularity(MONTHLY).conversation_directions(["business_initiated"]).dimensions(["conversation_type", "conversation_direction"])
I've set the headers correctly and provided the access token, but in response to this call, the API only returns the WABA ID:
{"id":"233923529797984"}
I'm not getting any analytics data in the response. What could be the reason for this issue, and how can I retrieve the conversation analytics data properly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

There are many reasons for getting such response ,
like first one is no conversation made in this provided time line
second if you are selecting monthly then make sure to pass correct start and end of that month ,
if still you got same issue , try passing WEEKLY instead of MONTHLY , and pass start and end accordingly , You can try daily too . just to check that data is there or not .
